# What is the correct method to find if a QScrollBar is visible?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qscrollbar

Method 1: `my_widget.verticalScrollBar().visibleRegion().isEmpty()`

Method 2: `my_widget.verticalScrollBar().isVisible()`

Method 3: ?

What is the best approach finding when a scrollbar is visible or not?

Comment: It depends, when/where do you need this? In any case, it normally is by checking if the scroll bar policy is not `ScrollBarAlwaysOff`, if the minimum is less than the maximum, if the size hint is not empty, and eventually if the scroll bar is transient (if the style supports it).